# Webview fails to load html assets in iOS error 10814

Tags: ios, flutter, webview

I'm using Flutter to power a web-view based app with 3 flavors set up for dev, staging and production. In Android, everything is working. On iOS, if I build using the dev flavor, it all works with no problems. But once I build using staging, it refuses to load any html files in the webview, and gives this error:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E9F34555-FDA0-423F-9C2C-08AF109BEA7C/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/assets/appAccess.html" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

This is my first iOS app on flutter, so it's probable there's a basic setup error somewhere - but really not sure where to look, given it's working on android and iOS in developer flavor.